# thread 'disappears' when blocking on read() how do i debug it?

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have a multithreaded application, in c++ running under Linux (Fedora 27). One of the threads keep reading data from a file on the local disk using low-level IO (open, read, etc.) and supplies that data to a buffer that is rotated between other threads.

Now, i suddenly ran into a strange problem where read() would start blocking infinitely for no apparent reason at arbitrary offset into the file. I added a monitor thread that would detect this block (by setting a timestamp before entering read() ) and attempt to shut down the program when it occurred.

The weird thing now, is that at the end of the main thread, it waits for `pthread_join`, and on that read thread - it returns 0 (success).

I tried again, but replaced the call to `read()` with a `while(1);` and now, `pthread_join` does not finish as expected.

I then examined the program in gdb, and to my surprise when i reach the `pthread_join`, the read thread is GONE!

Looking at `info thread` when the monitor thread detects a blocking `read()` the thread is still there, but at some point it disappears, and i can't catch it!

I'm trying to catch this thread exiting and i'm looking for ideas on how to do so. I am using `pthread_cleanup_push/pop` but my function is not being invoked by the read thread (all other threads do).

any ideas? i'm at my wits end!

edit ----------------------------------------

it appears to have something to do with `syslog` being called from a completely unrelated thread.

Comment: would help to have an [mcve]

Comment: So you added code to shut down the program if it detects `read()` blocking for too long, and you observe that the thread in which the affected read occurs seems to spontaneously "disappear".  Chances are excellent that the thread is *terminating* rather than disappearing mysteriously, and this is supported by the fact that you can afterward `pthread_join()` it.  With nothing else to go on, I'd suppose that the watchdog code you added is responsible, one way or the other.

Answer (score 1):

`read` is a cancellation point, so if your application calls `pthread_cancel` to terminate the thread at some point, the thread will cease to exist (after executing the cleanup actions).  Joining a canceled thread succeeds and yields the special value `PTHREAD_CANCELED` for the `void *` value optionally filled out by `pthread_join`.

If you replace `read` with an endless loop, then there is no cancellation point, the cancellation request is not acted upon, and `pthread_join` will also wait indefinitely.